# Graphics designing issue in iPhone development

Tags: iphone, ios

We use xcode  3.2.5 and iOs 4.2 for developing  iPhone application .

We are developing a shopping application. We have  to developing the application for both iPhone  3 and iPhone 4 .

Client gave us all of the screens and graphics . In a text file user clearly describes all of control’s (Button, Label, Table view, picker view) size , text color , background color, background images) . Client also describes spacing within all components.

User gave the entire screen in 640X960 pixels and control back ground in different size. Client doesn’t give us permission to resize any of these.

But when we set the background in  any of the image then after running a small part of the image shown in the simulator.

If we set uimageview in the xib then the image does not looks okay and we don’t use two big button besides one another.

But xib size is 320X460. How can I set two 180X180 pixel’s  button besides one another.

To show product list we have to use custom table view . Custom cell shows product information. We have used label , button in the custom cell. When we click on the cell the whole cell color will be blue.

But we have to set action only the button not in the whole cell.

Comment: Formatting, spacing, and paragraphs can make your question more readable.

Comment: Thanks....But i were happy if any one can suggest me to solve the problem..

Answer (score 1):

You have to resize it. 640X960 is for iPhone4G for iPhone3G you need 320X480. Every image used in app must have two versions:

- image.png - for iPhone3
- image@2x.png for iPhone4.

if you call

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"image"];
```

you will receive image in resolution required by the device, standard resolution for iPhone3 and high resolution for iPhone4.

Explain to client that this is platform requirement.

Comment: also please note that if you display the status bar you'll not have to give up some pixel (use [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame] to get the right value) on the the vertical size of current orientation.